# How to read a Delimited Text file in Java?

Tags: java, apache-camel, transformation, mapper, csv

We have following SEQ file from SFTP:

```
TSID ,D4 ; TEST ID # (PRIMARY)
TSNAME,A15 ; TEST NAME COMMON (ALTERNATE)
TSRNAM ,A15 ; PORT NAME
TSRELO ,A5 ; TEST REPEAT LOW VALUE
TSREHI ,A5 ; TEST REPEAT HIGH VALUE
TSSSRQ ,D2 ; SAMPLE SIZE REQ.
TSCTYP ,D2 ; CONTAINER TYPE
TSSUOM,A6 ; SAMPLE UNIT OF MEAS
TSINDX ,D4 ; WIDE REPORTING INDEX (ALTERNATE)
TSWKLF ,D2 ; WORKLIST FORMAT
TSMCCD,A8 ; MEDICARE CODE + MODIFIER 1 (ALTERNATE)
TSTADY ,D3 ; RESULT TURN-AROUND TIME IN DAYS
TSENOR ,A1 ; TEST HAS EXPANDED NORMALS Y/N
TSSRPT ,A1 ; ELIGIBLE FOR STATE NOTIFICATION REPORT Y/N
TSPLAB ,D2 ; SENDOUT LAB
```

The content of file are simple text like:

```
0001MONTH COMPOSITE                                     12319909110940                                                                                                                                MONTH COMPOSITE                                     
0002MONTHLY CAPD                                        12319909120944                                                                                                                                MONTHLY CAPD                                        
0003CAPD MONTHLY LS                                     123199100110021004100510081010101210151016101811620944105917931794                                                                            CAPD MONTHLY LS                                     
0004CCPD MONTHLY LS                                     12319910011002100410051007100810101012101510161018116209400942105917931794                                                                    CCPD MONTHLY LS                                     
0005HD MONTHLY LS                                       1231991001100210041005100710081010101210151016101809400942105917931794                                                                        HD MONTHLY LS
```

Is there any Java Internal package (or Third party Java library) available to read file Delimited file (.SEQ) in such a way to assign each value to POJO directly using some sort of converters?

For ex:

```
public class ra(){
  @SomethigLength (0,4)
  private String tsId;
  @SomethigLength (4,15)
  private String tsName;
}
```

(Note we are using Apache Camel here but i think camel may be complicated compare to any simple library?)

Comment: I have tried different library like Apache Commons CSV, openCSV but for large file both were taking too much time so we have written our own logic to parse the file. You can go for either openCSV or write your own logic.

Comment: I don't think there is a component available in Apache Camel that automatically converts it to POJO but you could have a look at https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/flatpack-component.html or https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/univocity-fixed-dataformat.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **camel-bindy** with Fixed-Length records(https://camel.apache.org/components/latest/bindy-dataformat.html#_4_fixedlengthrecord)

So your class will be like:

```
    @FixedLengthRecord(length = 15, paddingChar = ' ')
    public class Fastbox {

        @DataField(pos = 1, length = 4, align = "L")
        private String tsId; 

        @DataField(pos = 2, length = 11, align = "L")
        private String tsName; 
    }
```

and with **unmarshal()** you can convert the file to Java object.

More details are in the link above.

Hope it will help!

Answer (score 0):

After so much introspection i will use

http://fixedformat4j.ancientprogramming.com/usage/index.html